# How to display json array values in single UITableVIewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to display json array values in single UITableVIewCell my array :

```
Barbell, "EZ Bar", Dumbbell, Rope, "Resistance Bands", Machine, Cable, Kettlebell, "Body Weight"
```

UITableVIew numberOfRowsInSection in give my array count. when i display these array. it display each cell one buy one. but i need to display in one cell all the values.

In cell i want to show three values like this example.

[Barbell  EZ bar  Dumbbell],  then next values. please tell how to do it. I'm new for development.

Comment: some tutorial helpful for you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 and http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code add string whatever you want to use for join the components:

if you want to join by `space " "`

```
NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

if you want to join by `comma ","`

```
NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://gist.github.com/jamztang/6913749

Then you may use it using:

In interface file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *splittedArray;
```

In implementation file:

```
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Barbell", @"EZ Bar", @"Dumbbell", @"Rope", "Resistance Bands", @"Machine", @"Cable", @"Kettlebell", @"Body Weight", nil];

    splittedArray = [NSArray splitArray:items componentsPerSegment:3]
```

Then use each content of splittedarray in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

For example:

```
[self.splittedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```